# how to replace the user's roles collection with another one?

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm wondering how can I update a user roles, I've tried the following ways :
(**NOTE : User=Personne, UserRole= PersonneRole**)
Clearing the list and replacing it with a new one :

```
    @Transactional
    def myaction(Personne personne,List<String> roles){ // roles is a list of authorities
            def role
            personne.personneRoles*.delete()// tried PersonneRoles.findByPersonne(personne)*.delete() as well
            personne.personneRoles.clear()
            roles.each {  role=Role.findByAuthority(it);personne.personneRoles.add(new PersonneRole(personne,role)) }
            if(!personne.save(flush:true))
                return false
            ....
```

I've followed [this tutorial](http://spring.io/blog/2010/07/02/gorm-gotchas-part-2/) as well but didn't work :

```
@Transactional
def action(Personne personne,List<String> roles){
    def role
    def temp = []
    temp += personne.personneRoles
    temp.each{personneRole ->
        personne.removeFromPersonneRoles(personneRole)
        personneRole.delete()
    }
    roles.each {  role=Role.findByAuthority(it);personne.personneRoles.add(new PersonneRole(personne,role)) }
    if(!personne.save(flush:true))
        return false
...
```

in both case I get an error telling me that "....rejected value [ROLE_ADMIN_APP]
which is a valid role but is already after to the person, that's mean that the collection isn't cleared, any solution please? thank you

Comment: You may need to do a `personne.save()` between deleting the roles and adding the new ones.

Comment: have I to make the action @NonTrasctionnal ?

Comment: didn't work, I've tried to delete all the content and keept only :  
personne.personneRoles.clear()
personne.save(failOnError:true)  
but didn't work :/ do that have something to do with having PersonneRole belongsTo Personne?

Answer (score 3):

take a look in grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.SpringSecurityUiService in the spring security UI plugin https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-ui/blob/master/grails-app/services/grails/plugin/springsecurity/ui/SpringSecurityUiService.groovy and see how he does it. It drops all the associated roles and re-adds them (see void updateUser )

```
    UserRole.removeAll user
    addRoles user, roleNames
    removeUserFromCache user
```

Comment: removeAll does delete all roles but cannot create new roles :/

Answer (score 0):

here's what worked:

```
def myaction(Personne personne,List<String> roles){
        def role
        personne.personneRoles.clear()
        PersonneRole.removeAll(personne)
        roles.each {
            role=Role.findByAuthority(it)
            personne.addToPersonneRoles(new PersonneRole(personne,role))
        }
        if(!personne.save())
        ...
```

but I had to add :

```
personneRoles cascade: "all-delete-orphan"
```

to my class Personne or I get the following error :

```
A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [ma.ac.uir.ecine.authentification.PersonneRole#PersonneRole(personne:Personne(email:example0@gmail.com), role:Role(authority:ROLE_MEMBRE), id:null, version:null)]
```

anyone can explain to me why please?